# Heat equation and Bessel's function

Tags: mathematical-physics, heat

Could someone please explain why if the time-independent heat equation can, via changing of variables, take the form of Bessel's equation that the $\sqrt\lambda$ should take the values of the zeros of $J_0$ from [slides 20-21 of this powerpoint printout](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/IM/MATH2965/r/NOTES-Week-5.pdf)? Thank you.
(Also, what is that $a$?)

Comment: The $a$ is the radius of the disc (see slide 18). The need for $\sqrt J a$ to be a zero is because of that boundary condition ($u(a,t) = 0$; apparently the edge is in contact with a heat bath).

Comment: The link is now broken.

Comment: Sep 5th 2013: The question (which is not necessary off-topic) unfortunately had to be closed because of link rot. Let me use this opportunity to remind everyone in the future to give reference (i.e. mention author, title, etc.) of links so that we can reconstruct it in case of link rot.